# Get and Set attributes of a record

Tags: visualforce, record

I would like to get and set attributes of a record in a VF controller class without performing a query. I can get the current record id with any of the below methods. Can I read and write to attributes of these records without a query? I'm getting null values when I debug after getting or setting. Is there a better method(s) than those below? Thanks!

ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
recId = ctlr.getRecord().Id;
eng = (Engagement__c)ctlr.getRecord();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the record using the `getRecord()` method it will only pull in the values that are on the page.

Two ways to get additional field:

1. Without adding them to the page

   ```
    ctlr.addFields(New String[]{'field1','field1','field2'})
    eng = (Engagement__c)ctlr.getRecord();
   ```

**Note** there is still a bug where this will throw an error during test methods so you will have to wrap this to check if tests are running and populate the fields another way

2. Add the fields to the page layout

   ```
    <apex:outPutField value="......." rendered="false"/>
   ```

This will pull it into the controller record when you use the `getRecord` method.

Consideration:

Neither of these work to populate the value during a test, so if you are relying on the values to be populated solely via the above methods, you will have to do a query when performing tests, or pass the object with the fields populated when constructing the class....

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I'll give this a shot and will be sure to mark this as the best answer when it works. Thanks!